# Symfony2 per-user encrypted DB

Tags: php, symfony, encryption

I'd like to have an encrypted DB where the encryption key is at the user level (or even better at project level, see below). Is there an easy way to implement it in Symfony2?

Considering that users create projects which are accessible from several people, is there a way to share the key so that only users with the key can access a resource?

It would hence be a sort of 2 level authentication: one to sign in, the other to see the projects. Would it be safe to store those keys in cookies?

So basically I want to cover my back in case my DB gets dumped completely. Not even the administrator must be able to see the project details without the project's key.

Of course if the user loses the key he cannot have access to the resource any longer...any way to avoid that?

To make it clearer. I'm setting up a SaaS solution where end users (my customers) would be able to create "projects" and track how the project are going etc. You create a project and invite other people to it to see or edit stuff.

At this point the coding is at square 0. I'd like to offer an extra layer of security but don't know how.

Comment: This isn't as much a question about PHP/Symfony as it is a question about DB encryption. For a kickoff, if you want to encrypt a DB: what DB are you using MySQL? MSSQL? Pg? Secondly: what are these _"projects"_ you're talking about, and what are _"users"_ in this context? are users developers of various (interacting) SF2 projects? Are users clients, working in a SF2 based tool that manages their _"projects"_? There's just not enough to go on here, more details, some code - perhaps, showing us what you've tried, and what resources you've looked at...

Comment: Thank you, very relevant questions (I gave too much for granted ;) ). Now I detail more in my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to https://github.com/vmelnik-ukraine/DoctrineEncryptBundle/tree/master  "Bundle allows to create doctrine entities with fields that will be protected with help of some encryption algorithm in database and it will be clearly for developer, because bundle is uses doctrine life cycle events"

Comment: I came across that bundle, but the key is global. If someone had access to the configuration file it'd be able to decrypt the whole DB.